# Suppose that $f$ is entire and that for each $z$, either $|f(z)| \le 1$ or $|f'(z)| \le 1$. How can I prove that $f$ is a linear polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f$ is entire and that for each $z$, either $|f(z)| \le 1$ or $|f'(z)| \le 1$. How can I prove that $f$ is a linear polynomial? 
**What I have tried:**
I tried to use line integral to show
$$|f(z)| \le A + |z|$$where $A = max(1, |f(0)|)$ 
However, I was not satisfied with my approach. I am looking forward to hearing how you tackle it.